# 2D Game "jumping"

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have been working on a very simple 2d game in java, probably going to end up using it as a flash game or something when it's done, and I realized early on that I had no way of "jumping" for the "character" moved by the keys (a.k.a the green box in this code):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Color;

public class SquareGame extends JPanel{
    static final int SIZE = 400;
    static int x = SIZE / 2, width = 25, y = (SIZE / 2) - width, height = 25;
    public static SquareGame m = new SquareGame();
    public static void main(String[] args){
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(m);
        frame.setTitle("Square Game");
        frame.setSize(SIZE, SIZE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Action actionRight = new AbstractAction(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionRightEvent){
                if(x < (SIZE - width)){
                    x += (width / 5);
                }
            }
        };

        Action actionLeft = new AbstractAction(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionLeftEvent){
                if(x > 0){
                    x -= (width / 5);
                }
            }
        };

        Action actionUp = new AbstractAction(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionUpEvent){
                if(y > ((SIZE / 2) - (height * 2))){
                    y -= (height / 5);
                }
            }
        };

        Action actionRelUp = new AbstractAction(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionUpEvent){
                if(y < (SIZE / 2) - height){
                    y += (height / 5);
                }
            }
        };

        KeyStroke keyRight = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT");
        KeyStroke keyLeft = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT");
        KeyStroke keyUp = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE");
        KeyStroke relUp = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released SPACE");

        InputMap inputMap = m.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        inputMap.put(keyRight, "RIGHT");
        inputMap.put(keyLeft, "LEFT");
        inputMap.put(keyUp, "SPACE");
        inputMap.put(relUp, "released SPACE");

        m.getActionMap().put("RIGHT", actionRight);
        m.getActionMap().put("LEFT", actionLeft);
        m.getActionMap().put("SPACE", actionUp);
        m.getActionMap().put("released SPACE", actionRelUp);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawLine(0, SIZE / 2, SIZE, SIZE / 2);
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
        m.repaint();
    }
}
```

I thought adding the "key released" for the jump key would work, however that apparently only registers if the key is pressed and then released, not as long as the key is released. So, how do I add the math for jumping correctly? Also, I do realize that there may be a few other minor problems with this program, I am planning to get this all cleaned up after I figure out more with the character jumping and movement.

Comment: I think you need a key press and key release handler.  Key press flips a switch/flag indicating "jumping", key release sets the switch/flag back to false.  For some iteration while "jumpPressed", you execute logic to move your sprite appropriately in a jumping-like fashion.  I think some sort of timer might work well for that.

Comment: @CodeChimp So baically your suggesting that I add a boolean for `jumpPressed` and change it to true when the key is pressed and false when the key is released?

Comment: Yes.  I come from this conclusion in thinking about how most jump-enabled games work.  In most games, I believe the height/speed of the jump is controlled by how long you hold the jump key, up to some max amount.  In order to simulate that, I would think you would need to know when the keypress happens (start the jump) and when it ends (stop the jump, start the decent).  Since this is a game, I would think you would want to control the rate of ascent/descent.  Since the game will run at different frame rates depending on CPU speed, I would think you would want to control it on some timed loop.

Comment: Oh, and I would also think you would need to flag while you are mid-jump so that you prevent pressing the jump while in the middle of a jump from causing the jump logic from happening again and again, unless you want to support the classic "double jump", or even the metroid-style "spin attack" on double-press.